# oracle insert using DBlink

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have two different databases, say DB1 and DB2.  In both DBs I have a common table called test_emp, but there is a difference in the columns of the tables:

DB1

```
-----
desc table1
--------------
empno               number
ename               varchar2
sal                 number
hiredate            date
deptno              number
```

DB2

```
-----
desc table2
--------------
empno               number
ename               varchar2
sal                 number

insert into table1 select * from table2@DBLink_Name
```

But here I have a problem with number of columns, target table has more columns than the source.
Here I can't specify `column_names` because I am passing table as dynamic.

Can you somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the oracle data dictionary/metadata tables on both databases and generate the necessary sql for the insert. if `i_table_name` is your input.

```
select list_agg(column_name,',') columns -- comma separated list of columns
    from (
        select column_name
        from all_tab_cols
        where owner = 'XYZ'
          and table_name = i_table_name
        intersect
        select column_name
        from all_tab_cols@remote_database
        where owner = 'XYZ' -- could be different (?)
          and table_name = i_table_name
    )
```

You could then use this string (comma separated list of colums) to do something along the lines of..

```
v_sql := 'insert into ' || i_table_name || ' ' || '(' || 
                           v_column_list || ')' ||
         ' select ' || '( ' || v_column_list || 
                    ' from ' || i_table_name || '@' || remote_db_name;

dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
execute immediate v_sql;
```

I haven't tested the code. Make sure you print the insert and confirm it matches your expectations.

Comment: Why do you need more suggestions? What about this solution doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: @Ashok - if you have changes, please edit your question and let us know what changed. Frank - Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT a.*, 
       NULL, 
       NULL 
FROM   table2@dblink_
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - this relies on the column ordering of both tables. If one of the tables is dropped and re-created with a different column ordering, this will either fail with a conversion error or (much worse) silently insert wrong data.

Comment: The other problem is.. how do you know the number of 'null' columns you need to add (in the above case 2), if the OP is trying to generate this dynamically?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt and Rajesh :  The solution provided is not a generic one and I accept that. This is solution to OP problem only.